# Facebook escapes ampersand

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have a problem when posting on a user's wall with an application. If the message contains a "&" it will be encoded to `$amp;`

```
FB.api('/me/permissions', function(response) {
   if(response.data[0].publish_stream == 1){
       FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message:fb_review}, function(response) {
          if (!response || response.error) {
               alert('Error occured while trying to post to Facebook!');
          }});
```

So if fb_review is : ROZEL BAR & RESTAURANT the post on facebook will be ROZEL BAR `&amp;` RESTAURANT.

I have to do this from javascript and can't use PHP.

Comment: try `{ message: escape( fb_review ) }`

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried this and it doesn't work.

Comment: how about using `%26` for the &